# How to query/SELECT from a view table?

Tags: mysql

I created a view table for which I am trying to query from

```
drop view if exists salesdata;

create view SalesData as
select orders.order_id, items.item_id, (order_details.order_qty *   items.unit_price) as ItemTotal, items.title, artists.artist_id
from orders
join order_details
on orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
join items
on order_details.item_id = items.item_id
join artists
on items.artist_id = artists.artist_id
order by artists.artist_id
;

select * from salesdata;

select artists.artist_id, sum(order_details.order_qty * items.unit_price) as TotalSales
from SalesData;
```

However whenever I try to complete the query

```
select artists.artist_id, sum(order_details.order_qty * items.unit_price) as TotalSales
from SalesData;
```

ill get the following error

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'artists.artist_id' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select fields that are described in your view, try :

```
select artists.artist_id, sum(ItemTotal) as TotalSales from SalesData;
```

Answer (score 0):

The column names in the view don't include the table name prefixes from the `create view ... as select` statement, so don't include them when querying the view:

```
select artist_id, sum(order_qty * unit_price) as TotalSales
from SalesData;
```

You can also see the column names in the view using the following command:

```
describe SalesData;
```

Comment: I tried doing the query without the prefix however I get another error errorCode 1054 Uknown column 'order_qty' in 'field list'